# Getting debug information for a Method in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, reflection.emit

I'm working on a framework and part of it entails copying IL from a compiled method into a new `DynamicMethod` (with some very minor adjustments). Is there any way to read the debugging information for a method so I can copy that too and allow the consumer to debug the tweaked code?

FYI I plan to add debugging information using `ILGenerator.MarkSequencePoint`.

Comment: Maybe have a look at `mono.cecil` or `dnlib`.